User removed, bounty still associated to answer
Recently User 172436 was removed and their votes have been cancelled. That's OK with me.
However it seems their votes and even their bounties are still associated to the answers they voted for? Now the answer by helpful colleague EJ has +3 score and 100 bounties associated. The bounty is now awarded by Community. But the reputation has been deducted from the reps for EJ.
This is strange: showing this nice award, but no credits for it.

When a user is deleted, any active bounty and the associated reputation should be maintained. While EJ indeed lost a bit more than 100 rep attributed to "User was removed", I do not believe this includes the amount awarded by the bounty.
The "User was removed" value can include invalidated votes from more than one user and over a long period of time. Taking that into account, I think it is more likely that the total number of votes invalidated is a bit more than 10, rather than the system making an error.
Also, said answer now displays 1 upvote to me, so it seems there is some delay or caching on the display of the score. Clicking the score to get a breakdown of the votes should update the score.

I was rather confused by the timing of the events myself, but I believe you are right: my reputation notification drop-down lists two separate "user was removed" events for $-40$ and $-90$, respectively, neither of which could account for the 100 bounty. Indeed, it appears that two users (user172436 and user150715) were deleted in quick succession.

Thanks @EmilJeřábek for confirming. I hope you do not mind I involved you into this question.

Sure, no problem.
